# Is it possible to know if you view is MainView or DetailView of UISplitViewController

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a view that I want to use in the MainView and DetialView of a UISplitViewController but I need to be aware of which view it is in so it can behave correctly.  Is there any way to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view's controller will be in one of the two controller hierarchies in the `viewControllers` property of the [UISplitViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Traverse your controller's parentViewController chain to the `UISplitViewController` and then determine which branch it is in.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.splitViewController) {
        UISplitViewController split = self.splitViewController;

        UIViewController vc = self;
        while (split != vc.parentViewController) {
            vc = vc.parentViewController;
            if (!vc) break;
        }

        if (vc) {
            NSUInteger i = [split.viewControllers indexOfObject:vc];

            if (i == 0) {
                // self.view is on left side

            } else if (i == 1) {
                // self.view is on right side
            }
        }
    }
}
```